# How can I use dom-to-image or html2canvas with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html2canvas

I have been trying to capture a specific part of my webpage with html2canvas all day, but continuously received an error. I then decided to try dom-to-image, however, it is not working and it won't log data in the console for debugging.

My goal is to capture the portion of the background image contained inside a div and place it on the screen as an image. Seems simple, but has become very complex. Similar to https://www.squarspace.com.

Like I said I have tried html2canvas but to no avail. If you have a solution involving that library I would love to hear it! However, my code below is for dom-to-image.

```
export default {
    name: "WebsiteDevelopment",
    data() {
        return {
            windowWidth: 0,
            websiteHeader: "",
        }
    },
    watch: {
        windowWidth(newWidth, oldWidth) {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
                console.log(this.windowWidth)
                this.captureElement();
            });
        })
    },
    methods: {
        captureElement() {
            var node = document.getElementById('capture');
            domtoimage.toPng(node)
            .then(function (dataUrl) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = dataUrl;
                console.log(img.src)
                this.websiteHeader = require(img.src);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
            });
        },
    }
}
```

The code above does not log anything to the console, nor is `websiteHeader` updated. I expected the console to show me the URL, and the website header to then be defined as that URL.

> Update: I wasn't triggering the function captureElement(), but now I am and getting a new error.
>
> > Uncaught ReferenceError: domtoimage is not defined

Comment: How are you triggering the function?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I wasn't, good catch. However, now it says it doesn't recognize domtoimage. This could have also been my problem with html2canvas haha.